# vtiger 7.3 issue trying to save images in several modules - e.g. contacts, products, users

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Just migrated vtiger to V7.3.  Seemed to go OK but now, if I try to upload and image file to a user profile, a contact record or a product record, there is no error when the record is saved but the image is not showing when the record refreshes.

I also get an error using the Outlook Plugin when I try to link an email with an attachment.  It reports 'database query error'.  Linking emails without attachments works fine.

If I check the 'storage' folder, a file has been created for each attempt at saving an image (including the email attachments) but the name of the original image file no longer forms part of the filename.

A fresh install of V7.3 works fine and continues to work until I restore the live database at which point the problem appears.  Previously linked emails with attachments can be recalled and viewed correctly.

Anyone else seen this behaviour or have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried opening an issue at code.vtiger.com ?

Comment: Thanks Ruben - I've requested access to the community and await a response.